# how can I create a custom google map (of a place that does not exist)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it possible for me to create a custom map using Google Maps APIs of an imaginary place?

Are there examples of uses like that?

It would be of a group of islands, part of a story i'm writing...

If it is possible, are there exemples online?

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps Javascript API allows you to create a map and supply custom map tiles.

An example, the first I could find, is: http://maps.marlam.in/.

It's not easy and requires quite a lot of PNGs (if you want detail), but a description of how this particular example was built can be found [here](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1184658&s=8b3487e2e1beabb6dc5fa44ab98485c7&p=35995644&viewfull=1#post35995644)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a Google Maps API tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

You should take a look at the chapter about [Image Map Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes)

And [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image) you have a working example.